# execute a function against array items in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

Say I have an array and a function A:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
function A(p) { ... };
```

now I want to pass each item of `array` to function `A`, and want them to be executed in a sequential order. usually there won't be any problem. I can do:

```
array.forEach(function(item) {
  A(item);
}
```

however, if there are some asynchronous action in `A`, everything becomes messed up. so the question is:

**How can I have them executed orderly even if there are asynchronous actions in A?**

By which I mean, I want A('b') to be executed after A('a') is completely finished (including all the asynchronous actions in there).

I guess there must have been some utilities doing such things already. can someone shed me some light?

Comment: Did you try to pass function A as parameter to foreEach instead of wrapping it?

Comment: In your current form, it's mostly impossible, as the function `A` only accept one param, and it has no ability to notify server when it complete its works(the callbacks), so the server can't decide whether `A('b')` is complete or not.

Comment: @fubbe I guess it runs the same way. there's no guarantee of the async actions in A.

Comment: @fuyushimoya oh, yes. it doesn't have to look like this. callback is acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for "eachSeries" from [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)

You could use it this way

```
async.eachSeries(array, A, function(err) {
    // this function gets called at the end 
    // after your array has been looped
});
```

And you would have to modify your A function with a second parameter - a callback.

```
function A(p, callback) {
    // ...
    return callback();
}
```

That calls the callback parameter once your async calls in A are finished.

Comment: OK I'll try it. It's weird in the async document it mentioned this method, but there was no detail about this function. I thought it was an alias of `each`. I'll try and come back after a while.

Comment: OK this is what I'm looking for. thanks for the answer. and now I know why I missed this one. There was a note saying: `<name>Series - the same as <name> but runs only a single async operation at a time` I simply missed it.

Comment: They removed the detailed description a while ago and I think it was a bit easier to understand when it still was there.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) allow you to do just that.

This example is pretty convoluted, but it shows some aspects of using Promises:

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function processAsync(val) {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    console.log("Starting:", val);
    setTimeout(function () {
      console.log("Done:", val);
      res();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

arr.reduce(function(promise, i) {
  return promise.then(processAsync.bind(null, i));
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: I think this is a better solution if the OP is not already using `async`.

Comment: I was using async actually. but this is definitely an possible answer. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'],i = 0;
var A = function(p){
    //some code
    $.ajax({
        success:function(){
            try{
                A(item[++i]);
            }catch{
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Are you mean to this？

Comment: it's close, but I'm in server side with nodejs. anyway I've get the answer above. thanks for the help.